# R: Is it possible to 'copy/paste' data into R?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language. Suppose I see data in the following format in an internet browser (e.g. on a stackoverflow question):

```
weight   height age
1  2998.958 15.26611  53
2  3002.208 18.08711  52
3  3008.171 16.70896  49
4  3002.374 17.37032  55
5  3000.658 18.04860  50
6  3002.688 17.24797  45
7  3004.923 16.45360  47
8  2987.264 16.71712  47
9  3011.332 17.76626  50
10 2983.783 18.10337  42
11 3007.167 18.18355  50
12 3007.049 18.11375  53
13 3002.656 15.49990  42
14 2986.710 16.73089  47
15 2998.286 17.12075  52
```

**Question:** Is it possible to bring this data into R and directly make this data into a data frame (without reformatting, or minimum reformatting)?

Obviously, the following statement will not work:

```
my_data <- data.frame(weight   height age
                      1  2998.958 15.26611  53
                      2  3002.208 18.08711  52
                      3  3008.171 16.70896  49
                      4  3002.374 17.37032  55
                      5  3000.658 18.04860  50
                      6  3002.688 17.24797  45
                      7  3004.923 16.45360  47
                      8  2987.264 16.71712  47
                      9  3011.332 17.76626  50
                      10 2983.783 18.10337  42
                      11 3007.167 18.18355  50
                      12 3007.049 18.11375  53
                      13 3002.656 15.49990  42
                      14 2986.710 16.73089  47
                      15 2998.286 17.12075  52)
```

At the moment, I am manually doing this, e.g.

```
weight <- c("2998.958", "3002.208", "3008.171", etc. )
height <- c("15.26611", etc. )
age <- c("53", "52", etc.)

my_data <- data.frame(weight, height, age)
```

Is there a more "direct" (i.e. faster way) to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for something like the readClipboard() function?

Comment: @ Dr. Flow: thank you for your answer! I have never heard of this function before! How does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy in base R with the `text=` argument of `read.table`: you need to specify `header=TRUE` (to indicate that the first row is the column names) and `row.names=1` (to indicate that the first column is the row names).  It's convenient to put the optional arguments first, "out of order", so that they're visible above the big block of text.

```r
my_data <- read.table(header=TRUE,
row.names = 1,
text="
                         weight   height age
                      1  2998.958 15.26611  53
                      2  3002.208 18.08711  52
                      3  3008.171 16.70896  49
                      4  3002.374 17.37032  55
                      5  3000.658 18.04860  50
                      6  3002.688 17.24797  45
                      7  3004.923 16.45360  47
                      8  2987.264 16.71712  47
                      9  3011.332 17.76626  50
                      10 2983.783 18.10337  42
                      11 3007.167 18.18355  50
                      12 3007.049 18.11375  53
                      13 3002.656 15.49990  42
                      14 2986.710 16.73089  47
                      15 2998.286 17.12075  52
")
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather than `data.frame`. You can pass it to `read.table`

```
read.table(text="weight   height age
1  2998.958 15.26611  53
2  3002.208 18.08711  52
3  3008.171 16.70896  49
4  3002.374 17.37032  55
5  3000.658 18.04860  50
6  3002.688 17.24797  45
7  3004.923 16.45360  47
8  2987.264 16.71712  47
9  3011.332 17.76626  50
10 2983.783 18.10337  42
11 3007.167 18.18355  50
12 3007.049 18.11375  53
13 3002.656 15.49990  42
14 2986.710 16.73089  47
15 2998.286 17.12075  52", header=TRUE)
```

If the data is on your clipboard, you can do

```
read.table("clipboard", header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

The easier option is to copy the lines (`Cntrl + C`) and then use `soread`

```
library(overflow)
soread()
data.frame “mydf” created in your workspace
     weight   height age
1  2998.958 15.26611  53
2  3002.208 18.08711  52
3  3008.171 16.70896  49
4  3002.374 17.37032  55
5  3000.658 18.04860  50
6  3002.688 17.24797  45
7  3004.923 16.45360  47
8  2987.264 16.71712  47
9  3011.332 17.76626  50
...
```

check the

```
> str(mydf)
'data.frame':   15 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ weight: num  2999 3002 3008 3002 3001 ...
 $ height: num  15.3 18.1 16.7 17.4 18 ...
 $ age   : int  53 52 49 55 50 45 47 47 50 42 ...
```

---

If we want to rename it to a different object, change the `out` which is by default "mydf"

```
soread(out = "df1")
```

as the usage based on `?soread` is

> soread(
> sep = "",
> header = TRUE,
> stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
> skipAfterHeader = NULL,
> out = "mydf"
> )

---

It can be installed from the [github](https://github.com/mrdwab/overflow-mrdwab) with

```
source("http://news.mrdwab.com/install_github.R")
install_github("mrdwab/overflow-mrdwab")
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! I will try this right now! I wonder if there is a way to do this in base R?

Comment: @stats555 I am not aware of it.  Maybe you can also use `datapasta` which is again a package function

Comment: @ Akrun: thank you for your reply! I am still a bit confused about how this works. I installed the overflow library from github. I then highlighted all the data I wanted. I then entered the command: soread().

Comment: But here is the result: data.frame “mydf” created in your workspace
[1] soread..
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

Comment: Am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @stats555 you need copy the lines with `Ctrl + C`

Comment: OH, now it works! Thank you!

Comment: @stats555 there are ways in base R to read it, but I use this because it is so fast and easier to do instead of typing a lot with other parameters etc.